# Sensors controlled by Mobile Phone

Tags: mobile, solenoid-valve

I have a project which is of very low costs. The management has at least agreed for a cheap Mobile set and a solenoid valves. They have also agreed for a few extra project budget.

The solenoid valves requires 12v to open. It would be connected to a liquid dispenser unit. I am planning to use http://fonetwish.com/ USSD Mobile App to identify users and send data to web server.

But how can I control the solenoid valves via a normal mobile handset?

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer about your architecture. Where is the solenoid-operated valve located in relation to the mobile phone that you want to control it with? Where would the user be located?

Comment: The user would be like a user at ATM. The screens and menus would be displayed using http://fonetwish.com/ - the solenoid-operated valve would be located at the pipe outlet of a tank. So once the valve is open water would be dispensed until closed

Comment: What communications capabilities would the ATM-style terminal have? Does it _have_ to use a mobile telephony data link, or are there other options - internet via ethernet/router, bluetooth, wifi?

Comment: fonetwish.com gives all the facility - it does not requires any GPRS / Internet connection facilty - a user can just dial from keypad to get requested menus

Answer (score 2):

What cellular system is available in your area?

If you have GSM in the area use something like [this](http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=387490). I'm sure there are similar modules for CDMA networks.

Comment: Thanks but that board costs a lot and further we have a Mobile Handset with GSM SIM. Actually I am in need to a circuit that can make the sensor connected to Mobile phone and that instructions can be received from the phone , circuit to solenoid valve

Comment: Handsets are all different at the user connector side. You shouldn't have purchased just any handset but one that gives you the AT commands. This allows you to program your own interface. IMHO it is unlikely you're going to find an interface on such a small budget.

Comment: Thanks again. Ok I would them go for GSM Modem with SIM9000A modem but then again how can I control the sensor without a controller

Comment: If you know C or C++ just write a small application, either on a PC, Arduino, Raspberry, or a similar uP board. On an Arduino you have discrete I/O available to connect to the valves (relay needed). For a PC you got to slot-in a digital I/O board, USB I/O or something similar. If you still have an 'prehistorical' PC the parallel port can also be used to control the valves. Example: http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-the-relays-via-GPRS-SMS/

Comment: might be of interest to you: http://www.power7.net/GSM_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the details - I really appreciate your help and information as provided - but can I avoid using a controller. If I have a controller do I really need a Mobile - I can directly interact with them